# Chrome ignores onbeforeunload when visiting a top page (possible bug)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, preload, prerender

We run a file upload service. While files are being uploaded users need to stay on the page, so we use window.onbeforeunload:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'You still have files uploading...';
};
```

When the user tries to reload the page, close the page, or go to a new URL the browser warns him and he gets a chance to stay on the page.

This works, but we have found a strange behavior in Chrome.

When you try to go to the URL of a site you often visit it won't show the user the popup, but just quickly go to the requested page. In my case I could get this to work with reddit.com, facebook.com, but not dog.com.

I *think* it may have something to do with prerendering, or some other optimization that Chrome has, which makes it ignore onbeforeunload.

You can try it out by going to http://ge.tt and start a file upload. Then go to a different URL, and choose a website you often visit. Chrome should (incorrectly) let you do it.

Does anyone know what to do about this? Is onbeforeunload not something we should use any longer?

Comment: Tried to write an email on Gmail, then leave before it was saved as a draft. It was a little hard to do. Ended up pasting a large document. But yes, I could reproduce on Gmail. If I refresh the page Chrome warns me. If I go to reddit.com Chrome just lets me do it and deletes the email not yet saved as a draft. (edit: clarity)

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you PASTE a URL then hit Enter the event gets fired.  If you type the URL and rely on autocompletion, it does not fire.  Does it also happen in Safari?  You may want to sift through [these](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=onbeforeunload&colspec=ID+Pri+Mstone+ReleaseBlock+OS+Area+Feature+Status+Owner+Summary&cells=tiles)

Comment: Hmm, you are right about the pasting. Seems odd. It's easier to test on Facebook by the way. Start to write a status update, and leave the page. I'll test with Safari.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Safari. Seems to be Chrome only.

Comment: I think it may be fixed for Canary, but it may also be that I don't have a "top site" that would cause it to happen.